# ¿Hay una forma de detectar si una ventana esta abierta o cerrada en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Esto me lanza un error no se reconoce al método *ventanas*. Estoy tratando que el método me informe si la ventana de nivel superior está abierta o cerrada para que no la abra nuevamente, `disable` no es una opción válida.

```
class claseA ():

def __init__(self):

    self.root = Tk()
    btn = Button(self.root, text="Nueva Ventana", 
    command=self.ventanas).pack()

    ventanas.opened = False

    self.root.mainloop()

def ventanas():

    if (ventanas.opened):
        return

    ventanas.opened = True

    root2 = Toplevel(self.root)

    root2. wait_window()

    ventanas.opened = False

app = claseA()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No quiero ser ofensivo, pero el código en sí es muy malo y tiene muchos errores, así que solo me límitare a dejarlo medianamente funcional:

```
import tkinter as tk

class claseA ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.estado = True
```

fijate que el iniciador se declara con doble subrayado y que creo una variable boleana

```
self.root =tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="Nueva Ventana",command=self.ventana ).pack()
self.root.mainloop()
```

esto es basicamente lo mismo

```
def ventana(self):
    if self.estado:
        self.nueva= tk.Toplevel()
        self.estado=False
        self.nueva.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.cerrar)
```

Ahora compruebo el valor de estado si es verdadero ejecuto y asigno un estado de falso, además declaro un protocolo para cuando se cierre la ventana

```
def cerrar(self):
    self.nueva.destroy()
    self.estado=True

   
app = claseA()
```

lo único que hago en esta funciión es que  al cerrar la ventana devolverle el estado de verdadero por si se necesita volver a abrirla
Como dije, está muy feo, pero funcional y espero que orientativo.

Comment: Gracias crack, todo es bien valorado porque la intención es lo que vale.